# There is a difference in the runway lighting systems symbolized in the planview and the lighting system specified in additional runway information?

Tags: runways, aeronautical-charts, airport-lighting, lightning, symbology

Although two different lighting systems are symbolized for two runways in the airport plan view, the same lighting system is specified for runways 05 and 23 in the additional runway information section. Why? I am sharing the picture of Jeppesen symbols and the airport plan view below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not a pilot, so maybe I'm totally misreading what you've shown, but in your 2nd image, it appears to me that the symbols for `Rwy23` and `Rwy05` are distinctly different and are labeled differently (SSALS vs HIALS). Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Although they have different lighting systems, the common "HIALS" expression is used for both runways in the additional runway information section at the bottom of the chart.

Comment: This question is more clear than the other one, and answers itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HIALS stand for High Intensity Approach Lighting System.  (as opposed to MIALS for Medium Intensity...)

HIALS is a broad category of different approach lighting configurations, (all high intensity) but doesn't itself describe more detail like the specific number of light bars, spacing, etc.

As your second illustration clearly shows, a HIALS system could be configured as a Calvert, Calvert II, or even a SSALS, which stands for Simplified Short Approach Lighting System.  (presumably of high intensity...)

In other words, Calvert, Calvert II, SSALS and others are specific configurations, or arrangements of lighting within the category HIALS.

Comment: Thank you, sir.